# How to set up the parent page to capture an IFRAME's click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, mouseevent, jquery-events

I have set up a page (the parent) with an IFRAME (the child). What are the best methods for the parent to capture the click events of the child?

Addendum: Both pages are located on the same domain. jQuery is included.

Comment: Are the two pages on the same domain?

Comment: No jQuery? Is this a vanilla JS question only?

Comment: You must understand about same origin policy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FSame_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: Thanks guys. This isn't a vanilla JS question and yes the pages are on the same domain (so it's not an issue about cross domain policies)

Answer (score 0):

If all of your client browsers are MOZ capable, you can use the [`HTMLIFrameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement) reference which inherits all of the standard `HTMLElement` methods and properties.